# Get the lines of a file between two matching patterns which contains a specific pattern

Tags: shell

I'm trying to work with a XML file such as this one:

```xml
<clients>
    <client>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <age>12</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Carlos</name>
        <age>28</age>
    </client>
</clients>
```

I want to filter only the client tag with age equals to 18. I'm using a command i found googling around that gets all the "client" tags.

```bash
sed -n '/client>/,/<\/client/p' test.xml
```

Resulting this:

```xml
    <client>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <age>12</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Carlos</name>
        <age>28</age>
    </client>
```

I thought i could do something like that, but it doesn't work as i expected.

```bash
sed -n '/client>/(<age>18</age>)/<\/client/p' test.xml
```

Since it is not an option to download any external tool, i'm trying to use only core commands from Shell.

I'm expecting this result:

```xml
    <client>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </client>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an `awk` idea:

```bash
awk -v age=18 '
    /<client>/   { in_client = 1; node = "" }
    in_client    { node = node $0 ORS }
    /<\/client>/ { in_client = 0; if ( node ~ "<age>" age "</age>" ) printf "%s", node }
'
```

The method is to "slurp" each `client` node in a string variable and check if that string contains an `age` node that matches the "age" value given in argument.

###### limitations

As "is", it doesn't support:

- multiple `client` nodes in a single line
- nested `client` nodes
- any additional character in the `<client>`, `</client>`, `<age>` and `</age>` tags.

---

###### edit: some explanations

`awk` processes the input file(s) line by line; when a line matches a *condition*, it executes the associated block of *code*, that's what the `condition { code }` are.

1. ```
   /<client>/ { in_client = 1; node = "" }
   ```

   A condition of the form of `/regex/` is a regex match against the whole line (it is  equivalent to `$0 ~ /regex/`). Therefore, `/<client>/` means *« when the current line contains `<client>` »*. Then, the corresponding code sets the flag `in_client` to `true` (to indicate that we're *in* a *client* node) and initialize the `node` variable which will store the entire *client* node string.
2. ```
   in_client { node = node $0 ORS }`
   ```

   When we're in a *client* node, append the content of current line (i.e. `$0`) to the `node` variable. **note:** By default, `ORS` is a newline character.
3. ```
   /<\/client>/ {
       in_client = 0
       if ( node ~ "<age>" age "</age>" )
           printf "%s", node
   }
   ```

   When the current line contains the closing `</client>` tag, it should mean that we have the whole *client* node stored in the `node` variable, so we have to check if that *client* has the *age* that we're looking for (stored in the `age` variable); if so, then output the whole *client* node string. **note:** The form `var ~ "re" "g" "ex"` (instead of `var ~ /regex/`) is used when you need to build-up the regex from multiple strings.

Comment: Fravadona, though your solution has its limitations, i tried it and worked efficiently compare to the while solution Marijin proposed, it reduced the search time that was around 3 minutes to a few milliseconds and got all the tags within each client.

Comment: may i ask you to explain how these commands within the awk works? Just in case i need to apply a similar logic in the future and/or for those that might come here with a different idea be able to rearrange the code to their necessity.

Comment: @culpinha I added a few explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Of course using an XPath or XQuery tool is highly preferred over doing pattern matching. However, since the OP asked for an approach with only core tools, you can write a small parser that might work if the input is indeed so simple as in this question.

The OP didn't mention which shell they use, but here an approach in Bash that reads the file line by line, starts collecting a record when it reads `<client>`, reads until it finds `</client>`, and at that point checks if the search string is found, if yes the record is printed.

Code:

```
query="<$1>$2</$1>"

parsestatus=0
while read -r line; do
if [ $parsestatus -eq 0 ]; then
   # status 0, check for <client>
   if echo $line|grep -q "<client>"; then
      # client found
      result="$line\n"
      parsestatus=1
   fi
elif [ $parsestatus -eq 1 ]; then
   # status 1, check for </client>
   if echo $line|grep -q "</client>"; then
      # </client> found, check for query
      result+="$line\n"
      if echo $result|grep -q "$query"; then
         printf "$result"
      fi
      parsestatus=0
   else
      # line in between <client> and </client>, add to result
      result+="$line\n"
   fi
fi
done
```

Example run:

```
$ bash queryscript.sh age 18 < data.xml
<client>
<name>Bob</name>
<age>18</age>
</client>
```

Because the script reads from stdin you can pipe a second query on the results of the first. To get for example all records with age=18 that also have name=Bob:

```
bash queryscript.sh age 18 < data.xml|bash queryscript.sh name Bob
```

Comment: It is a solution indeed, Marijin. But as your did point out, this solution only work efficiently for a input simpler as the example. Since the XML i'm working with has many tags within this "client", it would take many "ifs" to control them.

Comment: @culpinha I generalized the script a bit to allow for compound queries (see edit). Now one if can handle all tags.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is impossible to parse an XML file with regex engines.

You could use [Xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) (available [here](https://nightly.link/benibela/xidel/workflows/main/master) for a few OSs) and a standard XPath expression:

```bash
xidel --output-node-format=xml --xpath '//client[age=18]' file.xml
```

```xml
<client>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </client>
```

Comment: Fravadona, this would be a solution if the environment i'm working at allowed me to use such tools, which is not the case. That's why i'm trying to find a "core" solution.